# Создание текстового редактора

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont, QIcon
from tkinter.filedialog import *
import sys
class Example(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.GUI()
    def GUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(300,300,300,300)
        self.setWindowTitle('Hi')
        textEdit=QTextEdit(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(textEdit)
        saveFile=QAction('Save',self)
        saveFile.triggered.connect(self.save)
        menu=self.menuBar()
        fm=menu.addMenu('File')
        fm.addAction(saveFile)
        self.show()
    def save(self):
        textEdit=QTextEdit(self)
        name=QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self)
        file=open(name[0],'w')
        text=textEdit.toPlainText()
        file.write(text)
        file.close()

if __name__=='__main__':
    app=QApplication(sys.argv)
    examp=Example()
    app.exec_()
```

Здравствуйте, не получается получить текст из QTextEdit. Если пользователь ввёл текст в текстовый редактор и сохранил его, то получается пустой файл.Помогите, пожалуйста, исправить эту ошибку.

Comment: полезное дело .. может быть когда не будь будем юзать редактор кода по имени Alice...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ошибка в том, что при сохранении автор создавал новый `QTextEdit` и брал его значение: `textEdit=QTextEdit(self)`

Попробуйте:

```
from PyQt5 import Qt
import sys


class Example(Qt.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle('Hi')

        self.text_edit = Qt.QTextEdit()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.text_edit)

        menu = self.menuBar().addMenu('File')
        save_file_action = menu.addAction('Save As ...')
        save_file_action.triggered.connect(self.save_as)

    def save_as(self):
        file_name, ok = Qt.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self)
        if not ok:
            return

        with open(file_name, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            text = self.text_edit.toPlainText()
            f.write(text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Qt.QApplication(sys.argv)

    example = Example()
    example.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 300)
    example.show()

    app.exec()
```

---

**PS.** У `QMenu` есть разные [перегрузки метода addAction](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmenu.html#addAction), например одна из них позволит передать: иконку, название, вызываемая функция и горячая клавиша (например, `Ctrl + S`), но я решил что это будет излишне для примера.

**PPS.** У [QFileDialog.getSaveFileName](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#getSaveFileName) есть параметры для указания заголовка, папки по умолчанию, фильтров. Например, можно сразу задать название сохраняемого файла

**PPPS.** Рекомендую в питоне не использовать верблюжью нотацию в названии методов и переменных: `textEdit` -> `text_edit`

Comment: А у `textEdit` не надо указать `self` в качестве parent object?

Comment: @bipll, виджеты автоматически получают parent, когда их добавляют на форму через layout (компоновщики) или через методы на подобии `setCentralWidget`

Comment: А, ну да, логично. :)

Answer (score 0):

попробуй перед `file.write(text)` добавить `file.write('')`

Comment: нет, Ошибка в том, что при сохранении автор создавал новый QTextEdit и брал его значение: textEdit=QTextEdit(self)